# How to fix Intellij idea not adding manifest to Artifact?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I ran into a problem which I cannot solve neither by cleaning, nor by deleting Artifact/recreating it. 
I stuck with it for several days now and google search doesn't know such problem.

So, I have a Gradle java project in Intellij Idea, and it doesn't extract my manifest to Artifact's jar.

It does it in a different project, but here it doesn't include manifest, so my jar says 
`no main manifest attribute, in txtadventureserver_main.jar`

[image]

Here's the Artifact screen - manifest is not there and I don't see how I add it

[image]

here's my gradle:

```
group 'com.vladdrummer.txtadventureserver'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'TextAdventureServer'
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile "com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.7.2"
}
```

Comment: Do you build artifact using "Build | Build Artifact" or using Gradle task?

Comment: build artifact. Actually, after 20 times of deleting/creating artifact Manifest finally appeared in Artifact list. I had to place it in a src/java directory first, and then next time I had to put it in resources dir and was added to artifact. This is nothing but a bug in Intellij Idea

Comment: Is there any news on this being fixed? It's really disappointing that JetBrains would miss a bug as important as this. From what I'm seeing you also can't just add the manifest in as a file and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: I selected my own manifest.mf but artifact-manager  apparently choosed the first manifest.mf from dependencies.

I solved in the following way (it's just a workaround, of course):

I edited <MyProject>/.idea/artifacts/<MyProject>.xml

```
<component name="ArtifactManager">
  <artifact type="jar" build-on-make="true" name="MyProject">
    <output-path>$PROJECT_DIR$/out/artifacts/MyProject</output-path>
    <root id="archive" name="myproject.jar">
      <element id="module-output" name="MyProject" />
      <element id="module-output" name="CmdLineArgsUtil" />
      <element id="extracted-dir" path="$PROJECT_DIR$/../libs/mylib-1.2.0.jar" path-in-jar="/" />
      <element id="directory" name="META-INF">
        <element id="file-copy" path="$PROJECT_DIR$/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" />
      </element>
    </root>
  </artifact>
</component>
```

and moved node "META-INF" immediately after node "MyProject" as in the following example:

```
<component name="ArtifactManager">
  <artifact type="jar" build-on-make="true" name="MyProject">
    <output-path>$PROJECT_DIR$/out/artifacts/MyProject</output-path>
    <root id="archive" name="myproject.jar">
      <element id="module-output" name="MyProject" />
      <element id="directory" name="META-INF">
        <element id="file-copy" path="$PROJECT_DIR$/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" />
      </element>
      <element id="module-output" name="CmdLineArgsUtil" />
      <element id="extracted-dir" path="$PROJECT_DIR$/../libs/mylib-1.2.0.jar" path-in-jar="/" />
    </root>
  </artifact>
</component>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can generate the MANIFEST.mf by going here in the Project Settings window:

[image]

Comment: That's actually how I did it. It's in the project, but not in Artifact